# Checking Existence and Value of Variable

Tags: ansible

I am building a play that requires the existence of a set of variables and also requires the variables to not equal `bar`. Below is an example of my definition of extra variables:

```
ansible.extra_vars = {
    A: "foo",
    B: "bar",
    C: "foo",
    ...
}
```

When my play runs, I see the following when I print a debug message for each item:

```
(item=A) => {
    "item": "A",
    "var": {
        "A": "foo"
    }
}
```

When I try the below evaluation, I would expect a failure on B, however all tests pass:

```
- fail: msg="bar is not a valid variable value for this play"
    with_items: required_vars
    when: var.{{ item }} is not defined or (var.{{ item }} is defined and var.{{ item }} == "bar")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I need to do to evaluate the value and cause a failure when `bar` is encountered?

Comment: Did you try with `var[item]`? Although I'm not really sure where `var` comes from.

Comment: I got `var` from the second code block that I pasted. I just tried `var[item]` and had the same effect as before.

Comment: Where/how did you define `ansible.extra_vars`?

Comment: That is defined in a config file that is used at runtime. The debug message confirms that extra_vars are making it into the playbook at runtime.

Comment: How are you populating the value into required_vars?

Answer (score 2):

`extra_vars` seems to be a dict, so you should use `with_dict` instead of `with_items`.

I'm not sure how exactly you did define `extra_vars`. When I define it in the playbook like below I get different output from debug. When I define it like  that (`ansible.extra_vars`) in a `group_vars` file I do not get any data in the playbook at all.

Also, when I use my `extra_vars` dict together with `with_items` I get the following error:

> fatal: [localhost] => with_items expects a list or a set

So there seems to be something strange about your `extra_vars`.

Here's my working example:

```
---

- hosts:
  - localhost

  gather_facts: no

  vars: 
     extra_vars: {
       A: "foo",
       B: "bar",
       C: "foo"
     }

  tasks:
  - debug: var=extra_vars
  - debug: msg="{{ item.key }}"
    with_dict: extra_vars
    when: item.value is not defined or (item.value is defined and item.value == "bar")

...
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

TASK: [debug var=extra_vars] ************************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "extra_vars": {
            "A": "foo", 
            "B": "bar", 
            "C": "foo"
        }
    }
}

TASK: [debug msg="{{ item.key }}"] ******************************************** 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'A', 'value': 'foo'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'C', 'value': 'foo'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'B', 'value': 'bar'}) => {
    "item": {
        "key": "B", 
        "value": "bar"
    }, 
    "msg": "B"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```